# Algorithm for array element multiplication in O(n)

Tags: arrays, algorithm

I need an algorithm which will compute below multiplication of array elements in O(n) arithmetic operations.

Let a1, a2, a3...an be sequence of integers. Need an algorithm to compute

∑_(1≤i< j≤n) aiaj

summation of product of ai and aj such that 1 < = i < j <= n

The required complexity is O(n).

Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks!

Comment: **hint**: factorize the product and see what you get.

Comment: Also, what did *you* actually try?

Comment: This is a homework question, I suppose.  Good instructor.  I like this one.  Yes, I think that I see how to do it (though in my case, I happen to have some past experience with this sort of thing).  You will have to apply some slightly creative mathematics before you can start programming.  @nneonneo's hint is right.  Another way to look at it is this: expand the product out in mathematical notation, *with a pencil* rather than a keyboard, for n=3 or n=4, and see what you get, then think back to high-school algebra.

Comment: (I understand that undergraduates find advice like the foregoing infuriating.  There is nothing like starting your due-on-Monday homework paper on a Sunday night, eh?  This is probably one of the more educational homework problems you'll see this term: it's a good one; it makes you think -- which, of course, the typical student faced with a deadline would rather not do right now.  We get it.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use two integers here.
Base of the following formula:

```
(a1 + a2) ^ 2 = a1^2 + a2^2 + 2*a1*a2

a1*a2 = ((a1 + a2)^2 - a1^2 - a2^2)/2.
```

The corresponding complex is: O(n) + O(1) + O(n) + O(1) = O(n).

NOTE: The first item of `(a1 + a2)^2` is short of `(a1 + a2 + ... + an)^2`.

Comment: Rats.  You are right, but you solved his homework problem for him.

Comment: @thb We can't be sure, but this question reads more interview question than homework to me. There's a creative insight needed (suggesting to me that it's not programming homework), but it doesn't involve a particular algorithmic technique (suggesting to me that it's not algorithms homework, and even if it is, most of the points in a well-graded classes will be for the writeup, and I would judge this one rather harshly (though it's fine for Stack Overflow)).

Comment: @DavidEisenstat: How does that work?  For an unofficial programmer, I have done a lot of programming over the past 30 years (I am a Debian Developer, for instance), but my education is in electrical engineering and my work, in building construction, so I don't know anything about software-development interviews.  Does the interviewer give you some questions, then let you go home and work on them a while?

Comment: How is the 1st term (sum( a1 + a2 )^2) of O(n) complexity?

Comment: @thb Usually the interviews are in person, at a whiteboard, but then some candidates go home and post the questions on the Internet (possibly violating an NDA in the process). People see them on other sites and ask them here.

Comment: @user1990169, the term (a1+a2) is O(n) complexity and the square only need O(1) operation.

Comment: @Steve Won't you have O(n^2) pairs of (ai + aj)^2?

Comment: @user1990169. We have got the summation of `(ai+aj)` which cost `O(n)`. We only need to do one more operation: square.

Comment: @thb. It is just an interesting problem. People who are interested in solving problems might read this problem on the websites or books and then post it here. By the way, I did not know answering this question would be called Rats.

Comment: @Steve Still not clear to me. Are you saying sum[ (ai + aj)^2 ] over all pairs of i & j (i<j) is an O(n) operation?

Comment: @user1990169. Sorry for the confusion, :). We did not need to got summation of all pairs of( i & j) here. The first term will be `(a1 + ... + an)^2` instead of `sum[(ai+aj)^2]`.

Comment: @Steve OK, now it is clear. But it will be better if you clarify this in your answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61246/discussion-between-steve-and-user1990169).

Comment: @Steve:  You are right: it is indeed an interesting problem.

Comment: @thb: You don't participate in answering process if you don't like to. This was an interview question for me in one of the leading companies and I am not an undergrad anymore. Though I answered it then, I needed an efficient solution, so posted it here. Thanks all for answering!

Comment: You reject my rebuke with commendable restraint.  Nice style.  Your correction is accepted.  Good luck at the new job.